# Yii2 crud generator

Tags: yii2, crud

When I add "Search Model Class" in CRUD generator in Yii2, the framework creates search class (ArticlesSearch) which extends controller class (Articles)- what for the search function is in the separate class (in ArticlesSearch). Why yii doesn't add search function to the controller (Articles)?

Answer (score 0):

The `ArticlesSearch` class generated by Gii should **NOT** extend a controller class. It should extend your article **model** (*app\models\Article*) which extends *\yii\db\ActiveRecord* if using a DB.

Yii won't expect all your logic to be handled on a controller. Your article model class may be used anywhere inside your app including other model controllers, cron tasks or console scripts. So having a model class named Article to define and handle all validations, relations with other models and interactions with DB then build a Search class extending it is a correct & flexible solution.

If you need searching to be tied to controller only, then you won't need to build any search class, just build and handle your `ActiveDataProvider` instances inside your controller.